# ¿Como puedo crear un elemento al pasar una forma en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]La idea es que al darle al boton de "Buy" en este caso, lo que pongamos en el input de "Ticker" y "Valor in $" haga crear un elemento en la caja de color verdiazul oscuro, de forma que simule como una "lista de inversiones" en este caso. En el input de Ticker se introduciría el nombre de alguna empresa como Apple o Microsoft, Tesla, etc. y en el Valor en $ un valor como 100, 200, 500, etc.

He intentado hacer el JavaScript con un template literal para intentar insertar el HTML y no funciona por alguna razón (sorry soy novato total en Javascript).

Este es el error que me sale: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el HTML, el CSS y el JS aqui:

```
----HTML---- 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="formdiv">
      <form class="form1">
        <label for="ticker">Ticker</label>
        <input type="text" id="ticker" />
        <br />
        <label for="value">Valor en $</label>
        <input type="text" id="valueinv" />
        <button type="submit">Buy</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="investmentsList"></div>
  </body>
</html>

----CSS----

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #091d3b;
  color: aliceblue;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 1880px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}

.formdiv {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: mediumaquamarine;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: slategray;

}

label {
  background-color: slategray;

}

input {
  background-color: orangered;
}

.investmentsList {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color:teal;
}


----JS---- 

"use strict";

let investmentList = document.querySelector(".investmentsList");



  document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function () {
    let nombreInversion = document.getElementById("ticker").value;
    let valorInversion = document.getElementById("valueinv").value;
    investmentList.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "afterbegin",
      `<p>Ticker: ${nombreInversion} Valor: ${valorInversion}</p>`
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás intentando acceder al onsubmit de un elemento que no existe en tu DOM usando

```
document.getElementById("form1")
```

En el HTML tienes `<form class="form1">`, deberías sustituirlo por `<form id="form1">` o acceder al elemento con `getElementsByClassName` o `querySelector`

---

Aparte de ese fallo, deberías controlar queel submit no hiciese el submit como tal y se quedase en la ejecución de tu función con:

```
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```